# Hibernate HQL DB2 Sequence

Tags: hibernate, db2, hql

We are using Spring MVC/Hibernate. I have a non-id column in the database which stores an unique id. We are using a DB2 sequence to generate the id. How do i get the sequence's next val programmatically using HQL/Native Query in Db2. I need to manipulate the id before storing them in main tables.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't Hibernate-specific, but the native SQL expression to grab the next sequence value is:
VALUES [NEXT VALUE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0023464.html) FOR *yourSequenceHere*
or
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR *yourSequenceHere* FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1